# qt remove window top frame border

Tags: c++, qt

Can I remove or decorate the white border of the window top border
i use qt::customizewindowhint[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a `borderless window`, reading the doc can help:

> Produces a borderless window. The user cannot move or resize a borderless window via the window system. On X11, the result of the flag is dependent on the window manager and its ability to understand Motif and/or NETWM hints. Most existing modern window managers can handle this.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum

```
 setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Is customizewindowhin not available?